# printing an array with a for-loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, printing

I've build an array with 10 plurals of 7 and am now trying to print it in reversed order with a for loop. but my program seems to be ignoring this code. I've no issues printing it in regular order with a for or a for each loop. 
What is wrong in this piece of code?

```
int[] numbers = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
     numbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10) * 7;
}
for (int i = numbers.length; i == 0; i--) {
     System.out.println(numbers[i]);
}
System.out.println("---");
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: In the second loop, myabe you intend:

    (int i = numbers.length; i > 0; i--)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array of size N in java has its indexes ranging from 0 to **N-1**. So in fact `numbers.length` is out of bounds - the last element in `numbers` is with index `numbers.length - 1`. Also not your condition should be `i >= 0` instead of `i==0`, otherwise your cycle will never be executed for an array of size greater than 1.

Comment: thank! I knew about the Array sizes and index ranges but I completely forgot to take it into account for my code. Netbeans didnt show me any error either, nor did java when I ran it. I've actually done this exercise before (but left the code somewhere else) and had no issues that time. Very frustrating to have them now! I did not know about the conditions.

Comment: @YoNuevo I believe it is more important to understand **why** the conditions are like this. If you understand how a for cycle works it will be way easier for you to debug your own code.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

`for (int i = numbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {`

in your reverse order loop.

Comment: Please take another look at the cycle. There is one more error that will prevent it from running correctly.

Comment: I did forget about the '-1' but I've added it to the code now and it still doesn't print anything. I dont understand why this program is ignoring this piece of code. It doesnt show my any error either.

Comment: @YoNuevo take a look at my answer you should also replace `i==0` with `i >= 0`.